# reRendering issue using @Formula annotation inside entity when use in jsf/richfaces component

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, seam2

I having problem with it comes to reRendering again on rich:scrollableDataTable, I have an onrowclick function that sends the item in my list to be in edit mode.

Here is the sample code:

```
                <a4j:outputPanel id="reviewerOP" ajaxRendered="true">           
                    <h:outputText id="to" value="#{_folder.reviewerName}">
                    </h:outputText>
                </a4j:outputPanel>          
                <h:selectOneMenu id="sridSO" value="#{folderBean.selectedReviewerId}" style="display: #{_folder.editmode == true ? 'block':'none'}">
                    <s:selectItems id="selectItes" value="#{folderBean.reviewersList}" var="_reviewer" label="#{_reviewer.userName}" itemValue="#{_reviewer.userId}"
                                   noSelectionLabel="--Select a Reviewer--"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>
        </h:column>
```

The value of my table point to the entity list with @SessionScope.

The scenario is when the user click the edit button the item in that particular row will be in edit mode and the drop menu will be enabled and the user will be able to select a reviewer for that folder. The property editmode is a transient property from The Folder Entity. So far good i am able to render correctly the drop down and save the selected reviewer in the DB. But i having problem with it comes to reRendering the reviewer name. On some occasion it does not reRender after the done button was clicked but on some part it works well.

The reviewName property used @Formula to get the name from the different table.

My question is: Is the @Formula had something to do on the delayed of reRendering or the scope of the entityList that gives the problem.

I am using seam.2.2 richfaces 3.x. and jsf2.0

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Already solved the problem.

I try to run some test on the result list that are return from my Entity List using some logs.
I found out that the property of my Entity are updated on the DB and as well as on the list. But the property that uses formula is not updated. So `refresh`() method wont work and will not reread the property annotated using `@Formula`. So i think that the query on my `@Formula` are cached by hibernate and will not reread on second access to the result list of Entity List.

My Solution:

The solution i use is to clear the `EntityManager` using its `clear()` method. And the list is updated correctly and the rerender works perfectly.

-cheers